# Getting an error code when deleting directory after mysqldump

Tags: mysql, bash, cron, find

I am currently running a cronjob executing a bash-script for a mysqldump.

```
#!/bin/bash
#

# define variables
TIMESTAMP=$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M)
USER=mysqluser
PASSWORD='myPassword'
BACKUP_DIR=/backup

# create directory with timestamp
mkdir -p "$BACKUP_DIR/$TIMESTAMP"

# dump database
# compress file with GZip
mysqldump --opt --user=$USER --password=$PASSWORD --host='host3.mydbserver.com' db1 | gzip -9 > ${BACKUP_DIR}/$TIMESTAMP/backup-db1-$TIMESTAMP.sql.gz
mysqldump --opt --user=$USER --password=$PASSWORD --host='host7.mydbserver.com' db2 | gzip -9 > ${BACKUP_DIR}/$TIMESTAMP/backup-db2-$TIMESTAMP.sql.gz

# find directories older than 120 minutes and delete recursively
find $BACKUP_DIR/* -type d -mmin +120 -exec rm -r {} \;
```

The script seems to be working fine dumping the data into sql files in a timestamped directory. After executing the dump the script is to delete all folders older than 120 minutes, but I am getting an error code 1 from the cron service saying the directory of the script is nonexistent. The output for the find command is

```
find: '/backup/2020-05-22_13:30': No such file or directory
```

Any idea how I can avoid this error?

EDIT 1: Once every couple of times I'm not getting the error code, without any changes in the code (it is currently running every 5 minutes for test purposes). I'm getting a feeling maybe this is a timing thing?

EDIT 2: I'm a noob regarding all things Linux, scripting, bash etc. and I spent days getting as far as I did. So any downvoters please leave a comment to let me know what obvious thing I overlooked.

Comment: have you tried to write a fider name with out : in it, it is nit forbidden, but you should try it anyway

Comment: Does this work: `find $BACKUP_DIR -type d -mmin +120 -exec rm -r {} \;`?

Comment: @nbk Yes, I've tried that, but there is no change. The script can create and delete the directories - only the last-to-be-deleted dir is causing the hiccup

Comment: @Roadowl This doesn't seem to change anything either. Interestingly the directory is getting deleted and I'm getting the error message anyway.

Comment: Try to add `-depth` to the find options: `find $BACKUP_DIR -depth -type d -mmin +120 -exec rm -r {} \;`.

Comment: I gotta go for now, but I'll try adding -depth to the options and see what happens.

Comment: @Roadowl Your tip is correct! I've added the -depth option to the find command and now the script runs as it should!

Comment: I'll post it as answer, so you can upvote that,

Comment: @Roadowl I upvoted, though to being new here it's not shpwing up

Answer (score 0):

Try to add -depth to the find options:

```
find $BACKUP_DIR -depth -type d -mmin +120 -exec rm -r {} \;
```